# Ternary to return undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to include a property on an object only in the event that a variable is defined. I don't want the property at all otherwise. I don't even want it to equal a blank string. I'm thinking something like this:

```
someFunc({
    bing: "bing",
    bang: (myVar) ? myVar : undefined,
    boom: "boom"
    }, "yay");
```

In the event that `myVar` is undefined, I want this to result in the same thing as the below:

```
someFunc({
    bing: "bing",
    boom: "boom"
    }, "yay");
```

Am I doing it right?

Comment: Looking back at it, I should probably have written (myVar === undefined) to prevent it matching a set false val. Anything else?

Comment: it all depends on which falsy values you want to leave out. `undefined`? `null`? `0`?

Comment: The title requests a ternary expression, but the accepted answer does not contain a ternary expression. Boo!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a **difference** between this:

```
var ex1 = {foo: undefined};
```

and this:

```
var ex2 = {};
```

Therefore, here's how I would do it:

```
var args = {
    bing: 'bing',
    boom: 'boom'
};

if (typeof myVar !== 'undefined') {
    args.bang = myVar;
}

someFunc(args, 'yay');
```

Comment: Of course, the difference is kind of subtle.  The `in` operator can tell the difference (`if (foo in ex1) { … }`, as can for … in loops (`for (foo in ex2) { … }`), but off the top of my head those are the only two cases where it makes a difference.  Notably, `typeof ex1.foo === typeof ex2.foo === "undefined"` and `ex1.foo === ex2.foo === undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

i would do something like

```
var config = {
    bing: "bing",
    boom: "boom"
};

if (typeof myVar !== 'undefined') config.bang = myVar;

someFunc(config, 'yay');
```

you have to be careful of javascript truthiness and falsiness.  The if statement in my example only puts bang on config if myVar is defined, but it works if myVar is defined as false.

Comment: I guess it makes more sense to add it when it exists rather then to delete when it doesn't exist.

Comment: myVar is the variable, not bang.

Answer (score 1):

Use rest operator.

```js
var obj = {
    bing: "bing",
    ...(myVar ? { bang: myVar } : {}),
    boom: "boom"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be

```
var args = {
    bing: "bing",
    bang: myVar,
    boom: "boom"
}

if (myVar === undefined) {
    delete args.myVar;
}

someFunc(args, "yay");
```

Clearly adding it when it exists is better then then deleting it when it doesn't exist.

The point is to treat something like it really isn't there it is safest to use the native [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/delete) to remove a property from an object.

You can hack it using setTimeout and callbacks. I recommend againts this

```
var args = {
    bing: 4,
    bang: (myVar === undefined) ? (function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            delete args.bang;
        }, 0);
    })() : myVar
}, "yay");
```

Comment: @MattBall that's your own fault for using a truthy ternary check in your own question. I'm showing you how to `delete` not how to handle your own boolean logic.

Comment: @BoltClock @MattBall I'm talking to person and phrasing it very aggresively. I mean to say I used the logic given in the question

Comment: chill out. Unless I misread your question, you originally had `if (!myVar) { ... }`, and then you edited it, in which case my point about `myVar` being falsy, but not necessarily undefined, is moot.

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {
    bing: "bing",
    boom: "boom"
}

myVar != null && obj.bang = myVar;

someFunc(obj, "yay");
```

The above code gets the job done. I don't think that you can do it directly inside the function call.

Comment: Why not use (the more readable) `if (myVar) obj.bang = myVar;`?

Comment: @Marcel If you mean the && operator - I prefer `x && y = x;` to `if (x) { y = x; }`

Comment: Yeah, I meant the last comment about the use of `&&` above an `if` statement; the OP wasn't very explicit about the condition (text: `x != undefined`, code: `(x)`).

Comment: @Marcel I tend to overuse && these days. I guess it's a phase or something :) Though, && can be very useful if you need a conditioned function call. For instance: `validate(x) && process(x);` instead of `if ( validate(x) ) { process(x); }` (for the case where validate(x) returns true/false depending on whether or not x validates).